# Referenciando Variáveis em Funções Importadas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, importação, escopo-de-variáveis

Estou aprendendo Python por conta própria e em muitos vídeos e matérias os programadores aconselham e enfatizam a importância de *"códigos limpos e organizados"*. Assim sendo, estou experimentando criar classes e funções em arquivos separados para então importá-las e utilizá-las em um arquivo principal, mas encontro o seguinte problema:

Num arquivo separado (Funções.py por exemplo) criei uma função que faz uma pergunta e a armazena em uma variável global:

```
def Pergunta(X):
   global Resposta
   Resposta = input(X)
```

Digamos, agora, que eu queira imprimir uma saudação dentro deste mesmo arquivo:

```
def Pergunta(X):
   global Resposta
   Resposta = input(X)

print('Sejam bem-vindos, {}!'.format(Resposta))
```

Fazendo isso, se o nome for `"Fulano"` o programa retorna:

```
'Sejam bem-vindos, Fulano!'
```

Agora minha dúvida: se, num outro arquivo, eu importar essa mesma função adicionando a variável `Resposta = ''`, como a seguir:

```
from Funções import Pergunta

Resposta = ''
Pergunta('Qual é o seu nome?')
print('Sejam bem-vindos, {}'.format(Resposta))
```

O resultado é que o programa não reconhece o `input` que eu gostaria de atribuir (mesmo assinalando a variável como global) e retorna:

```
'Sejam bem-vindos, !'
```

Se possível, alguém sabe me explicar por que isso acontece quando importo a função para um novo arquivo ou como posso obter esse resultado de forma correta?

Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Em vez de depender de uma variável global, eu acho que faz mais sentido a função simplesmente retornar o valor digitado. Mais ou menos assim: https://ideone.com/iHfYok

Comment: Boa noite, hkotsubo, agradeço a atenção! Então... Vi o arquivo e essa abordagem até funciona, mas minha dúvida é se isso funciona quando eu importar a função pra outro código/arquivo.py

Comment: Sim, funciona: https://repl.it/repls/DenseSunnyProprietarysoftware

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Consegui finalmente sentar pra testar e essa abordagem de fato funcionou. Agradeço a ajuda! Ficou a dúvida sobre o que acontece com variáveis nesse caso, mas vou tirar um tempo para estudar mais a fundo. Gratíssimo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Python, as chamadas variáveis globais não são verdadeiramente "globais" - felizmente. Isso as torna gerenciáveis.

O modelo que você está tentando fazer não é o melhor - mas faça assim, ganhe alguma experiência e com o tempo vai achar jeitos mais consistentes.

Então - quando uma variável é declarada como `global` dentro de um módulo, ela se torna uma variável daquele *módulo*. Então ela pode ser acessada por outras funções, seja naquele módulo, seja por código em outros arquivos, da mesma forma que você acessa as funções do mesmo módulo: com o operador "." usado como sintaxe de acesso a atributos:

```
import funcoes

def funcao_no_outro_modulo():
    print(funcoes.Pergunta)

    ...
    funcoes.Resposta = "a resposta descoberta nesse outro modulo é X"
```

Se você tentar importar a variável direto do módulo, com código como `from funcoes import Pergunta` - você vai ter uma referência para o conteúdo daquela variável como ela estava no momento em que o comando `import` foi executado. Mas para strings e números (e outros objetos imutáveis), se a variável no módulo original assumir outro valor, ela vai apontar para outro objeto. E a variável que temos no módulo em que fizemos  a importação, vai continuar relacionada ao objeto inicial.

Então, neste exemplo:

modulo1.py:

```
from modulo2 import Estado, mudar_estado

print(Estado)
mudar_estado()
print(Estado)
```

Modulo2.py:

```
Estado = "inicial"

def mudar_estado():
    global Estado
    Estado = "intermediário"
```

se você executar o modulo 1, vai ver "inicial" impresso duas vezes.
Se reescrever o módulo 1 como:

```
import modulo2

print(modulo2.Estado)
modulo2.mudar_estado()
print(modulo2.Estado)
```

vai ver a alteração.

É fácil ver que se você tiver tão poucas quando umas 4 ou 5 variáveis dessas em arquivos diferentes, o programa começa a ficar imprevisível e ingerenciável - é por isso que eu disse: experimente e ache uma prática legal.

Um caminho pra ir, que fica melhor, é manter *todas* as variáveis que vão
manter valores que você queira acompanhar a partir de várias funções em 
um único módulo - tipo `variaveis.py` - e dai usa sempre

```
import variaveis

variaveis.Pergunta = "que dia é hoje?"
```

Quando entender isso, é só entender melhor os elementos do seu problema, reprenta-los como classes em vez de módulos como funções, e pronto - em vez de variáveis globais você vai ter atributos de objetos, e um programa "crescido" :-)

Comment: Gratíssimo, jsbueno! Estou quebrando a cara de pouco em pouco, mas aprendendo! Acho que entendi o que acontece. Vou tentar essa abordagem que sugeriu. Estou estudando Classes e POO e o próximo passo é tentar pensar mais assim. Agradeço a atenção e a explicação!